# Center a button using zurb foundation css in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am using zurb foundation css in my rails application. I am having trouble centering the submit button in the form. The button is always at the left.

```
<%= form_for @campaign do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :content %>
      <%= f.text_area :content %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit :class => "button radius success text-center", :value => "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

There has to be a simple class that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center a button you need to wrap it in a element with the `text-center` class. 
Thats just how centering elements with CSS the `text-align` property works - it will center inline and inline block child elements. But not itself.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <label>Name</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
      <input type="submit" class="button radius success" value="Create">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm glad I learnt something new today.